# I keep getting this error when I run this code while working with OpenGL in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, opengl, graphics, jar

I keep getting this error when I try to run this skeletal code. I am trying to work with OpenGL in Eclipse. I can't figure out what is causing this problem. How can I fix this? I have added the jar files to the user library as well.

**CODE:**

```
import com.jogamp.opengl.GL2;
import com.jogamp.opengl.GLAutoDrawable;
import com.jogamp.opengl.GLCapabilities;
import com.jogamp.opengl.GLEventListener;
import com.jogamp.opengl.GLProfile;
import com.jogamp.opengl.awt.GLCanvas;
import com.jogamp.opengl.glu.GLU;
import java.lang.Math;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

class ThirdGLEventListener implements GLEventListener {
/**
 * Interface to the GLU library.
 */
   private GLU glu;
/**
 * Take care of initialization here.
 */

   public void init(GLAutoDrawable gld) {
       GL2 gl = gld.getGL().getGL2();
       glu = new GLU();
       gl.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
       gl.glViewport(-250, -150, 250, 150);
       gl.glMatrixMode(GL2.GL_PROJECTION);
       gl.glLoadIdentity();
       glu.gluOrtho2D(-250.0, 250.0, -150.0, 150.0);
    
   }
/**
 * Take care of drawing here.
 */
   public void display(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {
       GL2 gl = drawable.getGL().getGL2();
       gl.glClear(GL2.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    /*
     * put your code here
     */
   }
   public void reshape(GLAutoDrawable drawable, int x, int y, int width, int height) {

   }
   public void displayChanged(GLAutoDrawable drawable,
       boolean modeChanged, boolean deviceChanged) {

   }
   public void dispose(GLAutoDrawable arg0){

   }
}


public class Trial423Class{
   public static void main(String args[]){
    //getting the capabilities object of GL2 profile
       final GLProfile profile=GLProfile.get(GLProfile.GL2);
       GLCapabilities capabilities=new GLCapabilities(profile);
    // The canvas
       final GLCanvas glcanvas=new GLCanvas(capabilities);
       ThirdGLEventListener b=new ThirdGLEventListener();
       glcanvas.addGLEventListener(b);
       glcanvas.setSize(400, 400);
    //creating frame
       final JFrame frame=new JFrame("Basic frame");
    //adding canvas to frame
       frame.add(glcanvas);
       frame.setSize(640,480);
       frame.setVisible(true);
   }
}
```

THIS IS THE ERROR I KEEP GETTING.

**ERROR:**
[error1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T6rGu.png)

[error2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BIb3c.png)

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 out of bounds for length 1
at jogamp.opengl.windows.wgl.awt.WindowsAWTWGLGraphicsConfigurationFactory.chooseGraphicsConfigurationImpl(WindowsAWTWGLGraphicsConfigurationFactory.java:171)
at com.jogamp.nativewindow.GraphicsConfigurationFactory.chooseGraphicsConfiguration(GraphicsConfigurationFactory.java:424)
at com.jogamp.opengl.awt.GLCanvas.chooseGraphicsConfiguration(GLCanvas.java:1560)
at com.jogamp.opengl.awt.GLCanvas.addNotify(GLCanvas.java:611)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.addNotify(Container.java:2804)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.addNotify(JComponent.java:4839)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.addNotify(Container.java:2804)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.addNotify(JComponent.java:4839)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.addNotify(Container.java:2804)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.addNotify(JComponent.java:4839)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.JRootPane.addNotify(JRootPane.java:729)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.addNotify(Container.java:2804)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.addNotify(Window.java:791)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Frame.addNotify(Frame.java:495)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.show(Window.java:1053)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.show(Component.java:1728)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.setVisible(Component.java:1675)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.setVisible(Window.java:1036)
at Trial423Class.main(Trial423Class.java:65)

Comment: Why didn't you copy and paste the error?

Comment: I think you have to do this stuff on the AWT event thread, i.e. inside EventQueue.invokeLater. Usually it works anyway but maybe JOGL is particularly sensitive to this mistake

Comment: Copy pasted the error

Answer (score 1):

[It's a library bug. Update the library.](https://forum.jogamp.org/Crash-in-WindowsAWTWGLGraphicsConfigurationFactory-td4040703.html)

> Good catch, thank you.
>
> This typo was introduced with my commit:
>
> ```
> commit 0a6a592c04a85d8124aa9d38b67f0caa1d739b75  
> Date:   Fri Dec 10 05:24:32 2010 +0100
> ```
>
> now fixed via commit
>
> ```
> commit d335d99df25cc929d06765c3f1af3944f124f6a7
> Date:   Mon Jun 15 01:21:44 2020 +0200
>     Fix 'typo' in branching, valid config index is >= 0 (not < 0)
>
>     This issue was introduced in commit 0a6a592c04a85d8124aa9d38b67f0caa1d739b75
>     and the '2nd choice branch' obviously never tested.
>
>     Thanks to Lathanda finding this issue on 6/14/20.
> ```

Comment: I suspect you will still have a different problem after this. I think the buggy code only runs if your graphics card is not compatible. But update the library and find out.